How to include the build JDK in MANIFEST.MF using Gradle
I have a project with a build.gradle file that looks (in part) like this:
tasks.named('jar') {
    manifest {
        attributes('Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Build-Jdk'      : "${System.properties['java.version']} (${System.properties['java.vendor']} ${System.properties['java.vm.version']})",
                'Build-Jdk2'     : project.java.toolchain,
        )
    }
}


// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

The system version of the JDK is ZuluFX 11.  However, the project is being built against ZuluFX 21, per the languageVersion setting.
The resulting MANIFEST.MF includes this:
Build-Jdk: 11.0.21 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.21+9-LTS)
Build-Jdk2: {languageVersion=21, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}

That is, it's showing the JDK used to execute Gradle, not the JDK used to build the project.  I can include the toolchain settings, but those are just the settings used to find the JDK to build with, not the details of the JDK that was found.
How can I include the identity of the JDK actually used to build the project?

You can use the JavaToolchainService provided on the extension named javaToolchains (docs).
First you can secure a reference to the toolchain spec you are using:
def projectToolchain = java.toolchain {
    languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
}

And then use the JavaCompiler provided via the compilerFor method to get and arrange the details in the format you need:
tasks.named('jar') {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Implementation-Title': project.name,
            'Build-Jdk': javaToolchains.compilerFor(projectToolchain).get().metadata.with {
                "$languageVersion ($vendor $javaRuntimeVersion)"
            }
        )
    }
}

